# Implicit static constructor called before Main()

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version, c#-7.3

I have the following piece of codes.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Enterprise.Initialize("Awesome Company");
        // Assertion failed when constructor of 'Reg' class is disabled.
        Debug.Assert(Reg.Root == @"Software\Awesome Company");
    }
}

public static class Enterprise
{
    // Static Properties.
    public static string Company
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    // Static Methods.
    public static void Initialize(string company)
    {
        Company = company;
    }
}
public class Reg
{
    public static string Root = $@"Software\{Enterprise.Company}";
    
    // ctor.
    static Reg()
    {
        // Assertion failed when this constructor is disabled.
    }
}
```

When executed, the assertion passed. However, the assertion failed when the constructor for `Reg` class is disabled. On a closer look, I've found that the implicit constructor of `Reg` class is called before `Main()`. If the constructor of `Reg` class is explicitly defined, it will be called after `Main()`.

Why such discrepancy between implicit and explicit constructor?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue (VS2019, .Net Core 3.1) (I assume by "disable" you mean "comment out".)

Comment: what do you mean by "explicit" and "implicit" constructors? And how do you "disable" one? Those terms do not exist, as far as I know.

Comment: For me, this assertion IS NOT failed when this constructor is disabled.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm using vs 2019 .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: @HimBromBeere implicit constructor is the constructor that generated by the compiler when I do not define the constructor. Explicit constructor is the constructor that I define in the class.

Comment: This .Net Fiddle works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WoTkn9

Comment: @HimBromBeere I put a break point to the static field in `Reg` and the very beginning of `Main()`. Execution break at the  break point at the static field first  when no constructor is defined. From the stack trace, it shows the execution comes from (implicit) constructor.

Comment: just ysterday I got a very similar problem. The suprising answer was: "debugging a static constructor is dicy". You never *really* know what´s happening.

Comment: It is reproducable with .Net Framework: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yncMzC Looks like something was fixed in .Net Core

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as an "implicit (static) constructor". A type either has a static constructor or it doesn't... but that is part of what governs when the *type initializer* is executed.

Comment: @JonSkeet I got the "implicit (static) constructor" term from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Comment: Eek, that's not good. Will add some feedback to that page.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/20432 - hopefully Bill Wagner will sort it out :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a quirk of chained *static class initialization*.

From the [ECMA C# Specifications](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

> **15.5.6.2 Static field initialization**
>
> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
> sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in
> which they appear in the class declaration (§15.5.6.1). Within a
> partial class, the meaning of "textual order" is specified by
> §15.5.6.1. If a static constructor (§15.12) exists in the class,
> execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to
> executing that static constructor. **Otherwise, the static field
> initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to
> the first use of a static field of that class.**

Take special note of the last part, this is your problem, if you don't have a *static constructor* you have no control over when the field is initialized. In your test case they are being initialized before you call `Enterprise.Initialize`

In short, you shouldn't be relying on these rules, it's easy to make mistakes and is likely to cause weird issues.

Comment: Yes it indeed caused me some weird and funny issue. Will try to workaround it.

Comment: I ended up workaround the issue by defining static constructor in the static class to prevent compiler-generated static constructor from being called before `Main()`.

Comment: You could try [RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.runclassconstructor?view=netframework-4.7.2), which seems purpose made for addressing this.    I've used it during startup to avoid long waits on the first method call after an API starts.

Comment: @AjimOthy nice find, though i am not sure it will help in this situation. In truth chaining static classes should be avoided.